# WP Ecommerce Payment Gateway for Belgium

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, payment-gateway

I am really new to online payment integration on wp ecommerce - I was just searching all day long and I can't decide on what i should use and how to do this. One point is that I need to implement it for a customer from Belgium so he would like that all the payment forms to be in deutsch.

If anyone can advice me on this, I will appreciate a lot.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is very limited document for creating your own payment method in wp-ecommerce,

Best method i would suggest, Look at default payment like `authorize.net` , `paypal` and see , Which methods/class they have used.

Make clone of this functions with your Belgium Payment API & Response.